# Client IP address returns the same internal network address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the user's IP address from ASP.NET MVC 5. I've looked up various examples, such as these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/740431/177416
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20194511/177416
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003254/177416

They've all produced the same result: the user is considered internal to the network. I've had friends try their phones (which are not on the network). Here's my latest attempt:

```
private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
public static bool IsIpInternal()
{
    var ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    var logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, _logger.Name, ipAddress);
    _logger.Log(logEvent);
    try
    {
        if (ipAddress != null)
        {
            var ipParts = ipAddress.Split(new[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            var isDebug = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached;

            if (ipParts[0] == 10)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, _logger.Name, e.Message);
        _logger.Log(logEvent);
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The log is showing `10.xxx.xx.xxx` for all requests (based on the log). This is an internal address rather than the IP of the client connecting to the web app. The `IsIpInternal()` returns true always. What am I doing wrong?

Note that I'm ignoring `192.168.x.x` and `172.16.xxx.xxx` addresses as being internal.

Comment: Is your web site behind a proxy or load balancer?

Comment: @JohnWu, yes, we have a Citrix NetScaler that all our servers use. Could that be removing the original IP address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your web site is behind a load balancer, it is a common problem for the load balancer's IP address to appear when you are expecting the client's IP address. That is because in reality the load balancer is the only client that the web application knows is talking to it.

There are two ways to deal with this:

1. You can configure the load balancer to add an additional HTTP header ([x-forwarded-for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)) that specifies the original IP address. You will need to modify your web site to look at this header instead of the UserHostAddress, like this:

   ```
   //var clientIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
   var clientIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-forwarded-for"];
   ```

   Note: The x-forwarded-for header can actually [return a comma-delimited list of IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846970/getting-comma-separated-ips-from-http-header) in some cases. So to be compatible with such an occurence, you might write this instead:

   ```
   var clientIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-forwarded-for"].Split(',')[0];
   ```
2. You can configure certain LBs to pass through the client IP by copying the IP header packet. For Citrix Netscaler, see [this article](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX205670) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnWu. The sys admin added the header in Netscaler and now it works like a charm!

Comment: Great!  Thanks for confirming that it worked. We normally do option #1.

Comment: Yup, using that option and reading it via `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-forwarded-for"]`